# VS 2010 doesn't load PDB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a VS 2010 solution which I build in debug mode on a x64 Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.
The compilation produces a .pdb file next to the .exe.
When I run the project with the debugger attached I get the following error message:

> "Debugging information cannot be found or does not match. Loading
>   disabled by Include/Exclude setting."

At this point I cannot insert breakpoints in the code.
However, when I manually load the symbols (using the modules window) they are loaded correctly and I can again insert breakpoints.
I tried rebuilding, cleaning and recloning my code from the repository. Nothing helps. The .pdb obviously exists and matches. Why can't VS load them right away?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UPDATE:
So it turns out that there's an option to exclude specific symbol files from loading.

Go to:

> tools->options->debugging->symbols->Specify excluded modules

And make sure that nothing is excluded.